# VBA Audit Trail code throwing Argument Not Optional error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have built one database where the below audit trail code works flawlessly for both forms and sub-forms in Access 2010. But now that I am using it again in another database, I now get an error "Argument Not Optional" at the first `Call`. Why would this work in one database and not the other if they both have had the sub-form created the same exact way? I can not get the database to give me more information outside of the not so helpful error code. My best guess is that it has something to do with `Sub TrainingEntryAuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String, FormToAudit As Form)` but I can't really tell. Like I said, it works in one database, but not this one for some reason. Any ideas?

Module Code:

```
***ABOVE CODE OMITTED INTENTIONALLY***
'Audit module code for employee training entry form's sub form
Sub TrainingEntryAuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String, FormToAudit As Form)
On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctl As Control
Dim datTimeCheck As Date
Dim strUserID As String
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
datTimeCheck = Now()
strUserID = Forms!Login!cboUser.Column(1)

'Get computer IP address
Dim myWMI As Object, myobj As Object, itm
Set myWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set myobj = myWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
    For Each itm In myobj
        getMyIP = itm.IPAddress(0)
    Next

'If user is editing an existing record:
Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In FormToAudit
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        ![UserName] = strUserID
                        ![UserComputer] = getMyIP
                        ![FormName] = FormToAudit.Name
                        ![Action] = UserAction
                        ![RecordID] = FormToAudit.Controls(IDField).Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next ctl

    'If a user is creating a new record:
    Case Else
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
            ![UserName] = strUserID
            ![UserComputer] = getMyIP
            ![FormName] = FormToAudit.Name
            ![Action] = UserAction
            ![RecordID] = FormToAudit.Controls(IDField).Value
            .Update
        End With
End Select


AuditChanges_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub

'If error then:
AuditChanges_Err:
Dim strError As String
Dim lngError As Long
Dim intErl As Integer
Dim strMsg As String
strError = Err.Description
lngError = Err.Number
intErl = Erl
strMsg = "Line : " & intErl & vbCrLf & _
       "Error : (" & lngError & ")" & strError
MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical
Resume AuditChanges_Exit

End Sub
```

Before_Update code on subform:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord Then
    Call TrainingEntryAuditChanges("ID", "NEW") ***ERROR THROWN HERE***
Else
    Call TrainingEntryAuditChanges("ID", "EDIT")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Argument Not Optional` is thrown when you are calling a routine with the incorrect number of arguments required for that routine.

In your code

```
Sub TrainingEntryAuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String, FormToAudit As Form)
```

requires three arguments, `IDField`, `UserAction`, and `FormToAudit`.

However, in your `Call`

```
Call TrainingEntryAuditChanges("ID", "NEW") ***ERROR THROWN HERE***
```

you are only passing it two arguments: `ID`, `NEW`. You need to pass it a third argument (which looks like it will be the `form`). Try using `me` as the third argument to pass the 'current' form that is being updated and therefore calling the routine.